# Java files dosen't see maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, javafx

So I've been trying to set up my already existing project with maven and when I try to install it I get javafx.*** does not exist for every javafx import. I've tried changing the project structure but it never works. This is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.group-12</groupId>
  <artifactId>snake</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>snake</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>19</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
      <testSourceDirectory>test/main/java</testSourceDirectory> 

    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is my file structure.

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── com
│   │           └── group-12
│   │               ├── Controller.java
│   │               ├── Draw.java
│   │               ├── Food.java
│   │               ├── Fruits.java
│   │               ├── Game.java
│   │               ├── GameScene.fxml
│   │               ├── Grid.java
│   │               ├── GridPos.java
│   │               ├── Main.java
│   │               ├── MainGame.java
│   │               ├── Snake.java
│   │               ├── StartMenu.fxml
│   │               └── Window.java
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── group-12
```

I tried having different packages for different files but in the end I just but it all in the same folder.

I'm using neovim also so shouldn't be an IDE problem.

The application also worked perfectly before I tried to switch over to maven with no build tool.

Comment: Trying leaving out `<scope>import</scope>`

Comment: Still the same errors :/

Comment: The artifact id is wrong. You need (probably) `javafx-controls`. You may need other javafx dependencies too, depending on your application.

Comment: I strongly recommend following the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ for whatever IDE you are using.

Comment: The javafx-controls kinda worked, I'm at least getting a different error, when I run `mvn clean install exec:java` I get `Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project snake: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]` It then links to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException, but I just took the config from their own template so I don't see why it isn't working. sorry if I'm missing something obvious, first time using a build tool^^

Comment: The mainclass can be routed via property `<exec.mainClass>...</exec.mainClass>`

Answer (score 0):

I did add maven to an already existing project a while ago and I had the same problem. I got rid of it by clicking the "Reaload All Maven Projects" button in Intellij. That is the button that looks like a "refresh button" on the top left of the maven window

Comment: I do most of my stuff in the terminal and I've tried `mvn clean install -U` and that didn't work, just to make sure I opened Intellij and did the refresh but that also didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

**Approach**

As James suggests:

1. Use the correct JavaFX dependencies e.g `javafx-controls`.
2. It is better to start with a [maven project that works](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/CommandLine/Modular/Maven/hellofx) than one that is broken.
3. Follow official documentation at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs).

**Use the [`javafx-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) for executing JavaFX apps via Maven**

Copied from the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#usage) (with some simplifications):

> Create a new Maven project, use an existing one like [HelloFX](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/CommandLine/Modular/Maven/hellofx).
>
> JavaFX dependencies are added as usual:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
>     <version>19</version> 
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Add the plugin:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>0.0.8</version>
>     <configuration>
>         <mainClass>hellofx/org.openjfx.App</mainClass>
>     </configuration> 
> </plugin>
> ```
>
> Run the project:
>
> ```
> mvn javafx:run
> ```

Replace, the module, package and class name with your own.

As this is a modular project, the main class is fully qualified by module name and package name in addition to class name.  For non-modular projects, just leave off the module name and slash, e.g. remove `hellofx/` to just have `org.openjfx.App`.

**Incidental Advice**

I advise getting rid of the `sourceDirectory` and `testSourceDirectory` settings as your values are already the [default layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and maven works best when you follow the principle of [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).

Also, none of the lockdown stuff is really needed (my opinion, others could differ), so remove everything in `pluginManagement`.

**Don't use the `exec-maven-plugin` for executing JavaFX apps via Maven**

To address your comment:

> I'm at least getting a different error, when I run `mvn clean install exec:java`

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project snake: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

Don't use the `exec-maven-plugin` to execute JavaFX apps, it does not work.

The `exec:java` goal will try to run the JavaFX apps in the same process as the maven process, which won't have the JavaFX modules available.

You can use `exec:exec` then specify the `java` executable to execute and it will execute in a separate process, but then it won't have the module path by default.  You can supply the module path (supposedly via command line using `-Dexec.args="%modulepath"`, though that did not work for me) or via configuration in the `pom.xml`, which I tried, but that did not work either.  The JavaFX modules in maven are defined strangely with empty modules for non-classified dependencies and classified dependencies for the actual implementation.  The exec plugin module handling is not smart enough to work that out, so can't find the JavaFX modules.